# Uninitialise a lateinit var in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to test a scenario where my android app remains in the background for a while and some static variables which were lateinit get deallocated.

Is there any way I can manually Uninitialise a lateinit variable or free memory allocated to a certain object in kotlin ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "get deallocated"? If a lateinit variable keeps a reference to an object, this object will stay alive forever; it will not get deallocated.

Comment: Why are you using static variables?

Comment: You don't need to think about that, if your app goes into background system should kill your apps process and free all used memory.

Comment: Android kills background apps after a certain time so is there any class eg. service or worker that remains or lives differently from your application otherwise I guess you don't need to worry static variables(If not holds references).

Comment: @yole Yes that reference is kept, but when the app goes into background the variable is freed if it is a static variable I want to replicate that

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz my static variables are getting accessed after the app resumes

Answer (score -1):

I was able to achieve this via reflection

```
val prop = MyClass::class.members.find { it.name == "lateInitVar" } as KMutableProperty
prop.setter.call(MyClass, "null")
```